# Database storage with fast elementary queries and counts for 500M items

Tags: database, performance, storage, bigdata

I'm looking for a storage solution that is (only) fast for elementary queries and counts on a large but simple data set; there are no other constraints.

The data consists of **500 million items** shaped like the following:

```
{
    a: VARCHAR(100)
    b: VARCHAR(100)
    c: VARCHAR(100)
}
```

I want to solve the following **elementary queries** fast:
*“give me page X of items that where `a = X AND b = Y AND and C = Z`”*
Any of the three constraints are optional, e.g, `a = X` is also a valid query.
So I only want to query on field equality within a single row.
(Other queries are not important. Joins will never be necessary.)

Additionally, I want to have **fast count estimates** for each of those queries.
For instance, I'd like to know that there are approximately 2 million items where `a = X`.

**What storage solutions / configurations are the best match and why?**

Update: it might also be good to know that the underlying data rarely changes
and is added all at once in batches of ± 20 million items.

---

I currently tried ingesting the data to a MySQL database, with indexes on each of the columns. I got as far as 100 million items and the query performance is very good. However, the server has become extremely unstable and the import process halts randomly. I'm using `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: This is as base as RDBMS gets, I like postrgres but to each their own.

Comment: @ilanberci It seems indeeds as base as it gets, but I have huge difficulties handling such amounts with MySQL. That made me think it's perhaps not as base as it seems… Would PostgreSQL handle that better?

Comment: Please try postgres (I am not affiliated with them), it can easily handle that type of load.  Please ensure that each of your columns are individually indexed as you previously mentioned.  Also, if you are doing equality comparisons, use hash indexes instead of btree

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches, or search as well?

Comment: @Bertvan Only exact matches.

Comment: Have you tried building the indexes only after the data has been loaded? Is this for realtime or for analytical queries? How often does the data change?

Comment: @André I have considered switching off the indexes, but then I might be ingesting 500 million records only to have an index that takes a few days too build (if it works at all). That said, the data is ingested in batches of ±20 million triples, and almost never changes. Will add this to the question.

Comment: Well, you don't know, that it will take days to build. I don't think that 500 Mio records are big for mysql. You also might want to tune your autoextend increment, to keep the IO down: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoextend_increment

Comment: Something's really of with MySQL though, it really stutters on the ingest process. (Also, was using MyISAM, so autoextend does not apply. Would InnoDB work better?)

Answer (score 1):

How frequent are your terms, e.g are all a, b and c entries different? If not, mapping them to  integers would perhaps be a good idea to get queries faster.

Regardless, I suggest you to try the free and Open Source database MonetDB (http://www.monetdb.org/) (Disclosure: I work for the research group that builds it), the columnar approach might work very well here. I recently used it for a similar use case with over 100 billion rows, and it works great.

Comment: Thanks Hannes! Some entries will be repeated a lot, others will only occur one or two times. Will the overhead of first looking up the integer be worth it?

Comment: Integer comparisons are a lot faster than those on strings. If you  also sort your data by the most commonly queried column, you get binary search. But if there are not many strings, MonetDB's internal string representation (similar to a hash map) can work well, too.